# Encode / Decode .EXE into Base64

Tags: powershell, base64, encode, binaryfiles

I have a .NET exe file that I'd like to encode into a Base-64 string, and then at a later point decode into a .exe file from the Base64 string, using Powershell.

What I have so far **produces a .exe file**, however, the file isn't recognizable to windows as an application that can run, and is always a different length than the file that I'm passing into the encoding script.

I think I may be using the wrong encoding here, but I'm not sure.

**Encode script:**

```
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{   
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
$OpenFileDialog.filter = "All files (*.*)| *.*"
$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$FileName = $OpenFileDialog.filename
$FileName

} #end function Get-FileName

$FileName = Get-FileName

$Data = get-content $FileName
$Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($Data)
$EncodedData = [Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)
```

**Decode Script:**

```
$Data = get-content $FileName
$Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Data)
$EncodedData = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($Bytes))

$EncodedData | Out-File ( $FileName )
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The problem was caused by:

1. `Get-Content` without `-raw` splits the file into an array of lines thus destroying the code
2. `Text.Encoding` interprets the binary code as text thus destroying the code
3. `Out-File` is for text data, not binary code

The correct approach is to use IO.File [ReadAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
$base64string = [Convert]::ToBase64String([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FileName))
```

and [WriteAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) to decode:

```
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($FileName, [Convert]::FromBase64String($base64string))
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I'll try this today and will report back results.

Comment: Just to clarify, may I still use out-File on the $base64String you referenced above, after it's been converted?

Comment: @schizoid04, yeah, $base64String is plain ASCII text so you can use the standard text-based commands.

Comment: Quick note if you're trying to use this as a handy one-liner. I was trying to use the relative filename (I was already cd'd to my desktop) but the subcommand `ReadAllBytes(.\file.png)` was expecting "file.png" to be in %userprofile%.

Comment: I know I'm biased, using C#, but shouldn't this NOT WORK? I thought loading, converting, then saving it as `exe` again would break it...? Or is this some other method?

Comment: @Momoro an exe is just a file, not some magical thing, so naturally the answer works as `Convert` API is lossless when used with ReadAllBytes + WriteAllBytes that read/write the data as is without altering it.

Comment: Ohhhh... :) I thought he meant he would, say, put "TvqAAAA==" into the code, then save it :D now I understand what he wants :)

Comment: any reason not to use `Get-Content -Raw -AsByteStream` ?

Answer (score 57):

Just to add an alternative for people looking to do a similar task: Windows comes with `certutil.exe` (a tool to manipulate certificates) which can base64 encode and decode files.

```
certutil -encode test.exe test.txt
certutil -decode test.txt test.exe
```

Comment: So, I assume, then, that for encode, it's [File to be encoded] and then [file for resulting base64] ? (As far as syntax goes on that command?)

Comment: Do you know which versions this comes with? (All?) Are there any recent versions (7 and higher) for workstations (non-server OS) that might not contain this tool? The solution will be executed by an ITSM tool run on an end-users workstation.

Comment: I think all currently used Windows versions have this. But do your own research if you want to be sure.

Comment: I believe `certutil.exe` dates all the way back to Windows 2000, though it has gone through some changes since then.

Answer (score 12):

This is a purely PowerShell version of Swonkie's answer which, despite working quite well if you have access to the utility, isn't a PowerShell answer - which is what I needed.

```
$SourceFile    = "C:\Src\OriginalBinaryFile.dll"
$B64File       = "C:\Src\DllAsB64.txt"
$Reconstituted = "C:\Src\ReConstituted.dll"

[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($B64File,[char[]][Convert]::ToBase64String([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($SourceFile)))

[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($Reconstituted, [Convert]::FromBase64String([char[]][IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($B64File)))
```

As a side note.  If the DllAsB64.txt is created by certutil, it will be wrapped by these lines.

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

After removing these lines the PowerShell command above will decode it.  Certutil ignores them so it will decode its own output or the PowerShell output.

Comment: How is this any different from the accepted answer (by wOxxOm)?

Comment: People will be drawn by the question title rather than OP's problem.  wOxxOm's answer helps the OP but doesn't present a complete working solution that one, coming here due to the title, could simply grab and run with.  One could argue that the CertUtil answer doesn't even belong here but it's a good answer to the title question despite ignoring the underlying problem the OP had.  I wanted a PowerShell based answer that was as clear and succinct as the certutil answer for those uninterested in the details of the problem in the OP's code.